# How to process all items in List then complete with RxJava

Tags: rx-java2

I am investigating the use of RxJava in my current Android application.

I am stuck with the following use case.

For each data row on a particular database table I wish to action an HTTP POST call, once all the POST(s) have completed OK I need to clear down the database table.

The code I have is as follows:-

```
login()
                .andThen(Single.defer(() -> DatabaseController.fetchSingleRealmObjects(UpdateDO.class)))
                .toObservable()
                .flatMapIterable(update -> update)
                .flatMap(this::parameteriseUpdate)
                .doOnNext(NetworkController::update)
                .doOnComplete(() -> DatabaseController.deleteAll(UpdateDO.class))
                .ignoreElements()
                .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(e -> constructRetryHandler(retryCounter, e)))
                .doOnComplete(onComplete)
                .doOnError(onError)
                .doAfterTerminate(doAfterTerminate())
                .doOnSubscribe(compositeDisposable::add)
                .blockingAwait();
```

When the UpdateDO table is empty the above code completes as expected.

However when data rows exist the process "sticks" in the `doOnNext()`

I realise this is because I only call `emitter.onNext()`

```
private ObservableSource<Map<String, Object>> parameteriseUpdate(final UpdateDO updateDO) {
        final Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
        fields.put(FIELD_NAME_DRUG_ID, updateDO.getDrugId());
        fields.put(FIELD_NAME_STORE_CONTENT_ID, updateDO.getStoreContentId());
        fields.put(FIELD_NAME_STORE_ID, updateDO.getStoreID());
        fields.put(FIELD_NAME_ACTUAL_QUANTITY, updateDO.getActualQty());
        fields.put(FIELD_NAME_VARIANCE, updateDO.getUnitQty());
        fields.put(FIELD_NAME_REMARKS, updateDO.getRemarks());
        fields.put(FIELD_NAME_CREATED_BY, updateDO.getCreatedBy());

        return Observable.create(emitter -> emitter.onNext(fields));
    }
```

I cannot see how to fix this though, how to I refactor my code to allow me to have `emitter.onComplete()` called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is better to change that function from returning `ObservableSource<Map<String, Object>>`
to simple function like this

```
private Map<String, Object> parameteriseUpdate(final UpdateDO updateDO) {
    final Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
    fields.put(FIELD_NAME_DRUG_ID, updateDO.getDrugId());
    fields.put(FIELD_NAME_STORE_CONTENT_ID, updateDO.getStoreContentId());
    fields.put(FIELD_NAME_STORE_ID, updateDO.getStoreID());
    fields.put(FIELD_NAME_ACTUAL_QUANTITY, updateDO.getActualQty());
    fields.put(FIELD_NAME_VARIANCE, updateDO.getUnitQty());
    fields.put(FIELD_NAME_REMARKS, updateDO.getRemarks());
    fields.put(FIELD_NAME_CREATED_BY, updateDO.getCreatedBy());

    return fields;
}
```

and call it as a map not flatmap like this :

```
.map(this::parameteriseUpdate)
```

because in your case you are creating many streams that never complete.

Comment: that indeed fixed my issue and handles an empty table

Comment: @Hector glade to hear that :p